# Colliding wiith a smooth line of blocks

Tags: unity, collision-detection, platformer

I'm having a strange problem. I'm creating a 2D platformer, and creating the gameplay map by reading a csv file and placing prefabs of the appropriate type on map.

One part of the map is a simple straight line of blocks. I can move across them no problem except that there's this particular area where I simply can't move over it.

[image]

(In the image the blue tiles are the ones I'm colliding with. I added that to help debug it). The block itself is not higher than any other blocks in the rest of the line, comes from the same prefab et cetera.

If I remove "Fixed Angle" from the player character block, when passing from this block it'll start to rotate wildly instead - suggesting that it's colliding with some sort of edge.

Here's the code I'm using to generate the blocks

```
 for (int x = 0; x < tiles.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < tiles.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                var tile = tiles[x, y];

                if (tile.HasValue)
                {
                    switch (tile.Value)
                    {
                        case TileType.MAIN_CHARACTER:
                            Instantiate(mainCharacter, new Vector3(x * TILE_SIZE, -y * TILE_SIZE), Quaternion.identity);
                            break;
                        case TileType.NORMAL:
                            Instantiate(maintile, new Vector3(x * TILE_SIZE, -y * TILE_SIZE), Quaternion.identity);
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new NotImplementedException("No code for tile value " + tile.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So, what am I doing wrong exactly? Is there a way to tell Unity to ignore these 'tiny' collisions?

EDIT 1: If it makes any difference, I'm using BoxColliders2D around each block